# Update regex expression to consider multiple scenarios

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace `-`  in `test_string`:

```
import re
test_string = "refer- ences har- ness Stand- ard Re- quired www.mypo- rtal.test.com This - is a document"
re.sub(r"[- ]", "", test_string)
```

The expected result:

```
references harness Standard Required www.myportal.test.com This - is a document
```

Basically, the replacement should happen only when there is no white space before `-`.

How can I do so? Currently I get this:

```
referencesharnessStandardRequiredwww.myportal.test.comThisisadocument
```

I appreciate of someone could also explain the solution (not just give a correct regex expression)

Comment: `test_string.replace("- ", "")` ?

Comment: `(?<!\s)-\s+`?? If - as you say - the replacement should occur if there is no space before `-`, then `This - is a document` should stay as is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Right, sorry about the mistake in the output example.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You solution seems to be correct. Can you please explain it?

Comment: ```(?<!\s)-(?=\s).```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
test_string = "refer- ences har- ness Stand- ard Re- quired www.mypo- rtal.test.com This - is a document"
print(re.sub(r"(?<!\s)-\s+|", "", test_string))
# => references harness Standard Required www.myportal.test.com This - is a document
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f4OfHg/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Un3lF8).

**Details**

- `(?<!\s)` - a [**negative lookbehind**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if there is a whitespace immediately to the left of the current location
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars.

Comment: What exactly `<!` means in this regex expression `(?<!\s)`?

Comment: @Fluxy `<!` is part of a [**negative lookbehind** construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
test_string = "refer- ences har- ness Stand- ard Re- quired www.mypo- rtal.test.com This - is a document"
test_string = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]- ', '', test_string)
print(test_string)
```

Comment: Sorry, "This - is " should stay as it is