# Add a custom exception to the regex expression

Tags: python, regex

This question is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646224/update-regex-expression-to-consider-multiple-scenarios), for which I got an answer.

Now I need to add an exception condition into the recommended regex expression. The regex expression `(?<!\s)-\s+` should be applied only if the word after `-`  is not equal to `to`. If it is equal to `- to`, then the `-`  should be replaced with a single white space  .

I tried to use a negative lookbehind `(?<!to)` to add the condition on `to`.

```
import re

s = "refer- ences har- ness Stand- ard Re- quired www.mypo- rtal.test.com A - it is a document, move- to store"
re.sub(r"(?<!\s)-\s+(?<!to)", "", s)
```

But it still returns `moveto store` instead of `move to store`.

The expected output:

```
references harness Standard Required www.myportal.test.com A - it is a document, move to store
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
s = "refer- ences har- ness Stand- ard Re- quired www.mypo- rtal.test.com A - it is a document, move- to store"
print(re.sub(r"(?<!\s)-(?:(\s)+(to)\b|\s+)", r"\1\2", s))
# => references harness Standard Required www.myportal.test.com A - it is a document, move to store
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/L6pCLL) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TAALpS/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!\s)` - a location with no whitespace immediately on the left
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?:(\s)+(to)\b|\s+)` - a non-capturing group matching either of the two patterns:

  - `(\s)+(to)\b` - a whitespace captured into Group 1 (the group value is referred to with the `\1` placeholder, called a replacement backreference, from the replacement pattern), repeated one or more times (so that only the last one lands in the Group 1 memory buffer) and then a whole word `to` (since `\b` is a word boundary) that is captured into Group 2 (`\2` in the replacement pattern)
  - `|` - or
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces.

The replacement is a concatenation of Group 1 and Group 2. When the first alternative in the non-capturing group does not match, the `\1` and `\2` are empty strings, so the result is as expected in both cases.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain:) What is ` r"\1\2"` and what is `?:`?

Comment: That is a nice part using `(\s)+`, so you are left with exactly a space for the replacement am I correct?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, this is a common trick when you need to work around the lack of a conditional replacement pattern. Boost/PCRE2 are really nice as far as conditional replacement patterns are concerned.

Comment: I thought of a lambda checking for group 2 first etc..but this is cool. +1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, using a lamba is a valid way, too.